# Common SDL project for Visual C++ cross platform development

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cross-platform, sdl-2

I'm attempting to use Visual C++ cross platform features to write an SDL 2 app for Windows, Windows Universal, iOS, Android and Linux. I have one project for each platform now I want to abstract the SDL stuff to a common project that each platform project will reference with each project supplying the appropriate SDL libs for the platform through the linker.

Is there a project type in VS that actually allows me to do this? I was hoping the shared items project would do the trick, but I doubt thats the one. There does appear to be some form of shared library for iOS and Android, but it doesn't look like that extends to Linux and Win32.

Thanks,

Comment: Visual C++ and cross-platform doesn't go well together.

Answer (score 0):

To make a successful cross-platform application with SDL2, you should, in first place, use a compiler that's available on both platform. Because, you will need to compile a binary for each platform. SDL2 seems to support IOS and Android out of the box, but I don't know how deployment is done for the mobile OS. You can still use Visual Studio with CMake or a Makefile and use another compiler instead of Visual C++ to support a cross-platform build, like g++ (mingw32 on windows) or Clang.

Comment: VS has an ARM compiler now for iOS and Android dev, and for Linux it creates a connection to a Linux dev machine where I believe it calls the gcc compiler and sends it the source files. While I'm not certain, I think in terms of each platform project, VS has it sorted. Its the common project that all of those projects need to access where things get a bit confusing for me.